# Save events on before unload in Application Insights in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure

I'm trying to save custom metric - how long user was on mu page - using Application Insights. I wrote following code (it is a part):

```
        var start = new Date();

        var recordMetrics = function () {
            var end = new Date();
            var timeSpentTotal = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000;
            if (window.appInsights) {
                window.appInsights.trackMetric("timeSpentTotal", timeSpentTotal);
                window.appInsights.flush();
                console.log("Sent data with timeSpent");
            }

        }
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload",
            function (e) {
                recordMetrics();

            });
```

But every request after the flush is canceled. I'm almost sure that this is because App Insights create asynchronous AJAX request. Can I somehow change this to synchronous? Or maybe I do something totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you remove the following line of code: `window.appInsights.flush();`

This is described on the [API reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md).

> **`flush()`**
>
> Immediately send all queued telemetry. Synchronous.
>
> You don't usually have to use this, as it happens automatically on
> window closing.